# Fetch вместо XMLHttpRequest в конструкторе класса. Как сделать запрос синхронным.

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch

Помогите разобраться с использованием fetch для загрузки данных в конструкторе объекта.

Задача простая, есть объект. Свое состояние при создании в конструкторе запрашивает по API и получает через метод GET. Раньше для такой задачи я использовал  XMLHttpRequest в синхронном режиме. Все замечательно работало. 
Все говорят что метод старый надо переписать на fetch. И здесь я споткнулся. Все работает хорошо, но асинхронно. Т.е. код работает, объект создается состояние считывается. Но все это происходит в отдельном потоке. Код основного потока живет своей жизнью. Часть кода успевает воспользоваться объектом когда в нем еще нет корректных данных. Второй день не могу понять как заставить ждать код, пока не отработает конструктор объекта? Помогите разобраться как при fetch запросе заставить конструктор ждать пока не вернется результат.

Вот часть кода объекта:

```
    class Market {

   constructor(cityid) {

      this.items = [];
      this.loadItems(cityid);
   } 

   loadItems(cityid) {
      let url =`/ajax/get-products?cityid=${cityid}`; 
      let data;
      httpGet(url)
         .then(
            (response) => {
               try {
                  data = JSON.parse(response);
                  this.items = data; 
                  this.applyFilter();
                  console.log('We gets data:', this);
               } catch(e) {
                  myErrorHandler(e);
               }
            })
         .catch((e) => {
            myErrorHandler(e);
         });
   }
```

Так делаю запрос:

```
function httpGet(url) {

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url, false);

    xhr.onload = function() {
      if (this.status == 200) {
        resolve(this.response);
      } else {
        var error = new Error(this.statusText);
        error.code = this.status;
        reject(error);
      }
    };

    xhr.onerror = function() {
      reject(new Error("Network Error"));
    };

    xhr.send();
  });
}
```

Comment: лучше вынести запрос из конструктора вообще в метод. Синхронно никак не сделать

Comment: Синхронным он никогда не будет